# Run python script with dot slash ./

Tags: python

I installed two python 2.7.3 into my home directory

```
   one is for Linux:           /home/luban/Linux/Python/2.7.3
   another is for Solaris:   /home/luban/SunOS/Python/2.7.3
```

then I create a wrapper named "python" in /home/luban/bin to call the different python when I am working on different systems.

[luban@lunbanworks 1] ~ > cat /home/luban/bin/python

```
#!/bin/sh

CMD=`basename $0`

OS=`uname -s`


CMD_PATH="/home/luban/$OS/Python/2.7.3/bin"


if [ -x "${CMD_PATH}/${CMD}" ];then

    export PATH="${CMD_PATH}:${PATH}"

    exec ${CMD_PATH}/${CMD} ${1+"$@"}

else

    echo "${CMD} is not available for ${OS}" 1>&2

exit 1

fi
```

```
[luban@lunbanworks 2] `ls -l /home/luban/bin/python`

-rwxrwxr-x  1 luban lunban  221 Apr  5 19:11 python*
```

I use below script to  test the wrapper `/home/luban/bin/python`

```
[luban@lunbanworks 3] ~ > cat myscript.py

    #!/home/luban/bin/python

    myname="lunban"

    print "myname is %s" % myname

[luban@lunbanworks 4] chmod +x myscript.py
```

I want to use `./ run myscript.py`

```
[luban@lunbanworks 5] ~ >./myscript.py

    myname=luban: Command not found.
    lpr: Unable to access "myname" - No such file or directory
```

use `/home/luban/bin/python myscript.py` can work:

```
[luban@lunbanworks 5] ~ > `/home/luban/bin/python myscript.py`

    myname is luban
```

After I change the shebang line to `#!/home/luban/Linux/Python/2.7.3/bin/python`, use `./` can execute the script.

```
[luban@lunbanworks 6] ~ >cat myscript.py

    #!/home/luban/Linux/Python/2.7.3/bin/python
    myname="lunban"

    print "myname is %s" % myname

[luban@lunbanworks 7] ~ >./myscript.py

    myname is luban
```

Why  when I use `#!/home/luban/Linux/Python/2.7.3/bin/python` at the beginning of myscript.py, `./myscript.py` can work,

but if I use the wrapper `#!/home/luban/bin/python` in my python script, use `./`  to run the script, it cannot not work?

I had many scripts used `#!/home/luban/bin/python` when I only installed python  under `#!/home/luban/` for Linux, they can run with `./`, I don't want to change them,

so, how to let `./` run the python script If I want to KEEP wrapper `#!/home/luban/bin/python` as the shebang line?

---

DEIT:

`./myscript.py` can NOT work with the wrapper `#!/home/luban/bin/python` under `CentOS 5.4, Bash 3.2.25`

today, I have a test under `CentOS 6.4, Bash 4.1.2`:

I added

```
echo '$0 =' $0
echo '${COMMAND_PATH}/${COMMAND} ${1+"$@"} =' ${COMMAND_PATH}/${COMMAND} ${1+"$@"}
```

into the wrapper `#!/home/luban/bin/python` to track.

`./myscript.py` works with the wrapper `#!/home/luban/bin/python`

```
[luban@lunbanworks 20] ./myscript.py 
      $0 =  /home/luban/bin/python
      ${COMMAND_PATH}/${COMMAND} ${1+"$@"} =  /home/luban/Linux/Python/2.7.3/bin/python ./myscript.py
      myname is luban
```

So I suppose that it may be a Bash 3.2.25 bug for `./` when I use the wrapper `#!/home/luban/bin/python`?

Answer (score 8):

Have you considered:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

That generally works for me, so long as python is found in the search path.

In your case, you would want your profile to have the following in the profile setup:

```
# Adjust for your preferred shell
export PATH=/home/luban/Linux/Python/2.7.3:/home/luban/SunOS/Python/2.7.3:$PATH
```

Then, when your python script runs with the "#!/usr/bin/env python" shebang, it will find the right python for you.

Comment: I had many scripts used `/home/luban/bin/python`, someone also used it, I want to find a way to still keep `/home/luban/bin/python` in those scripts, not to find out all the scripts and change them to use `#!/usr/bin/env python`. Do I need to do some update for the wrapper `/home/luban/bin/python` I created?

Comment: Hmm.. differing bash versions, problematic. :(  

I tested on an Ubuntu box with bash 4.2 and your shebang->shell script wrapper works as expected. 

I hate to say it, but it might be better to bite the bullet and update the scripts that are referencing your wrapper script.

If the scripts are all on the same box, it would be fairly straightforward to find the scripts that are referencing your script using ack-grep, for instance:

ack-grep -ai '#!/home/luban/bin/python'

And then perform an in-line sed against those files to update the shebang line.